# Identifying this logic gate

Tags: logic-gates, nand

Could somebody please explain the two logic gates with only the one input, A and B, respectively??

[image: NAND gate with single input]

It is a NAND gate, with a box just before it.

What is this box?

Why only one input?

Comment: @Bimpelrekkie Thank you! If you make that an answer I will mark it as correct.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The box isn't a box, it shows that the signal goes to both inputs of the 2-input NAND gate. The fact that the line is slightly thicker (as thick as the lines used for drawing the NAND symbols) shows that whoever made the drawing didn't have a clue.

A better drawing would be:

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fOkgVT.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>

Comment: The book I took the photo from is infamous for being incorrect... Thanks for the great answer!

Comment: Perhaps worth mentioning--though it may be obvious--is that the reason this is done is to be able to use NAND gates as NOT gates, because when using discrete gates you tend to have a lot of spares of a single type due to how the 74 and 4000 series (and others) logic chips are designed. Better to use three of the gates on a quad NAND than to use two gates of a hex inverter and one of a quad nand, since then you only need one chip instead of two.